# jQuery autocomplete not working for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the two variables req and availableTags. Both having the same values. Autocomplete is working fine while I am using the availableTags in source element. This is not working while I am using the req variable in source element.

Note : I just copy and paste the req string into availableTags variable.

```
var req = JSON.stringify(selectOptions);

var availableTags = [{ "value": "INDIA", "id": "10" }, { "value": "0", "id": "11"}];

 { name: 'FLD_WS_ID', index: 'FLD_WS_ID', width: 150, editable: true, edittype: "text", editrules: { edithidden: true, required: false }, hidden: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 1, elmprefix: "&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='required'></span>&nbsp;" }, editoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (e) {
                                $(e).autocomplete({
                                    source: req, // availableTags working fine. 
                                    minLength: 1,
                                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                                        $(e).val(ui.item.label);
                                    },
                                    select: function (event, ui) {
                                        $(e).val(ui.item.label);
                                        $("input#FLD_WS_ID").val(ui.item.value);
                                    },
                                    change: function (event, ui) {
                                        if (!ui.item) {
                                            $(this).val('');
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        }
```

Comment: "selectOptions" is a json array object?

Comment: Try to change $(e.target)

Comment: @user3710059: I think, you don't need to do "JSON.stringify".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your real problem, but as per my understanding I suggest you to not use `JSON.stringify`. Means simply use :

```
var req = selectOptions;
```

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is used to convert the value into a JSON string.

In Jquery autocomplete you need to pass `JSON Data`

Comment: @user3710059: you could accept my answer as a correct answer !! :) Because it can help may other users to find a solution.